# Why does asp page load event fire again on javascript window.close?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a program where we are using training videos and exams supplied by an outside party to upgrade training on new regulation.  It includes an exam at the end.

I'm being asked to forklift this into our ASP employee site, which I've largely succeeded in doing.  I do want to capture the exam results, so, despite my rudimentary Javascripting skills, I did find the place in the Javascript coding where the exam results are calculated, so I have the Javascript open an asp.net page as a pop-up window, passing the exam score information to that page, and the page logs the results in the database.  The only items on the page is an acknowledgement that the information has been logged, displaying the captured information, and a button to close the pop-up, that fires the Javascript window.close event.  When the button is pressed, the scores are logged again, which should only happen in the Page Load event.

We're getting duplicate entries to the database, but the timestamp on the entries is not the same, so I know that part of the code is being run, again.

Here is the asp markup for that popup window:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <h4><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWelMess" /></h4>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="OK" ID="btnOK" />
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the Visual Basic Code Behind -

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim quizName As String = Request.QueryString("qn")
    Dim corrAns As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("ca"))
    Dim totQues As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("nq"))
    Dim examStatus As String = Request.QueryString("xst")

    logScores(quizName, examStatus, corrAns, totQues)

End Sub

Protected Sub logScores(ByVal qName As String, xStat As String, correct As Integer, qNum As Integer)
    Dim uID As String = Session.Item("USERNAME")
    Dim uName As String = Session.Item("FULLNAME")
    Dim testPerc As String = Format(100 * correct / qNum, "0.00")

    Dim connSQL As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString1").ToString)
    Dim procName As String = "AddExamScore"
    Dim cmdAdd As New SqlCommand(procName, connSQL)
    cmdAdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", uID)
    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("corrAns", correct)
    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("numQues", qNum)
    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("corrPerc", CDec(testPerc))
    cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", xStat)
    cmdAdd.Connection.Open()

    cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmdAdd.Connection.Close()

    lblWelMess.Text = uName & ", your score has been logged" & "<br />Quiz: " & qName & "<br />Status: " & xStat & "<br />Correct: " & correct.ToString & "<br />Questions: " & qNum.ToString & "<br />Percentage: " & testPerc
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Response.Write("<Script language=javascript>window.close()</Script>")
End Sub
```

Should I be closing that window or structuring the button-click event some other way?

Should I include some kind of code in the "logScores" sub-routine that checks to make sure it isn't fired by a window close?

Should I move that "logScores" sub to fire with a different event?

Comment: Can you check for IsPostback in your page load and omit logging?

Comment: Most ASP.NET Web Forms controls cause a postback to fire, for example when you click a button. That forces the page to reload. You can check if it's a PostBack or not, but that's silly. Why do you need a postback to close the page? Why do you need a server control at all? You know how to write a basic HTML button and wire up some JavaScript to run when you click it, right?

Comment: @RossBush - I'm feeling a bit dumb right now....

Comment: @mason - the entire site is ASP.NET based, and we (and I) don't have much Javascipt expertise.  I'm not adding that to the site, unless I have to, which I don't, here.  The "IsPostBack" check is very simple and works fine.

Comment: No, it's very complex. You're not seeing everything that happens. It's a waste of resources on both the client and server, and leads to a poor experience. You're not "adding" anything to the site by using pure HTML instead of server control. You're just using the correct tool for the job. `<button onclick="window.close()">OK</button>` is all you need. No server method, no postback, no extra markup or viewstate, no wasted bandwidth or extra HTTP requests. Everything all contained in one location.

Comment: @mason - ah, I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ASP.NET Web Forms controls cause a postback to fire, for example when you click a button. That forces the page to reload. You can check if it's a PostBack or not, but that's silly. Why do you need a postback to close the page? Why do you need a server control at all?

Instead, let's replace all of this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="OK" ID="btnOK" />

Protected Sub btn_OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Response.Write("<Script language=javascript>window.close()</Script>")
End Sub
```

with this:

```
<button onclick="window.close()">OK</button>
```

The difference is that your original way causes some JavaScript to fire, which causes an HTTP Post to the server, running through the entire page lifecycle, building a new instance of the page, running your button click handler, writing some JavaScript to the page that will cause it to close the window once it hits that JavaScript.

My way can be described as: some JavaScript fires when the button is clicked and it closes the window.

---

Note, stuff like this is why people like me dislike Web Forms so much. It might *look* easy but everything going on is far more complex than it appears. Instead, learning the basics of HTML and JavaScript and will serve you far better. It's better to use ASP.NET MVC which does less of this leaky abstraction stuff. Or switch to just writing HTML and JavaScript on the client (perhaps using Angular or React or Knockout etc) that communicates back to the web server via AJAX (perhaps with ASP.NET Web API) or web sockets (perhaps using SignalR). That's less leaky abstractions, cleaner HTML, easier to debug, faster for your clients, less resource intensive for clients and servers.

I'm not saying you can't use Web Forms and be successful. Like Ross's answer shows, there's usually a way to do things. But there's better ways out there.

Comment: @RossBush - Sorry to "un-best" your answer but this one is more elegant in its simplicity.  Both of you diagnosed the reason for the double-firing. Thanks@

Answer (score 2):

I bet that using the IsPostBack to determine if it is the initial request would fix your problem.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    if !IsPostBack Then Begin
        Dim quizName As String = Request.QueryString("qn")
        Dim corrAns As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("ca"))
        Dim totQues As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("nq"))
        Dim examStatus As String = Request.QueryString("xst")
        logScores(quizName, examStatus, corrAns, totQues)
    EndIf
End Sub
```

Comment: DUH!!! Postback is going to fire with the button press, even if it's just triggering the closing of the window/page.  As expected, it was something very simple/stupid.  Thanks for seeing the obvious that eluded me!

Comment: Glad I could help.